# React . How to save into a variable ,and not in console.log()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, console.log

I'm very new to React. I can see the right result with the following function using console.log(), but how can I save the result (it's a number, not an array), into a simple variable.

```
firestore.collection('games').where('user_ide', '==', uid).get().then( (snapshot) => 
    console.log(snapshot.docs.length),
    );
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to put the result into a state. For example with hooks

```
  const [state, setState] = useState("");


firestore.collection('games').where('user_ide', '==', uid).get().then( (snapshot) => 
console.log(snapshot.docs.length),
 setState(snapshot.docs.length)
);
```

Now the result will be in the state variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you utilizing states? if so then what you can do is initialize states above like this :

```
  const [
        snapShot,
        setSnapShot,
    ] = useState()
```

and use

```
firestore.collection('games').where('user_ide', '==', uid).get().then( (snapshot) => 
    setSnapShot(snapshot.docs.length),
    );
```

if its in somewhere you cant use a state, just use

```
let snapShot 
firestore.collection('games').where('user_ide', '==', uid).get().then( (snapshot) => 
        snapShot= snapshot.docs.length
        );
```